# Short lived DbContext in WPF application reasonable?

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, dbcontext, dbset

In his book on DbContext, @RowanMiller shows how to use the DbSet.Local property to avoid 1.) unnecessary roundtrips to the database and 2.) passing around collections (created with e.g. ToList()) in the application (page 24). I then tried to follow this approach. However, I noticed that from one  using [} – block to another, the DbSet.Local property becomes empty:

```
ObservableCollection<Destination> destinationsList;

using (var context = new BAContext())
{ 
   var query = from d in context.Destinations …;
   query.Load();
   destinationsList = context.Destinations.Local; //Nonzero here.
}
//Do stuff with destinationsList

using (var context = new BAContext())
{ 
   //context.Destinations.Local zero here again;
   //So no way of getting the in-memory data from the previous using- block here?
   //Do I have to do another roundtrip to the database here to get the same data I wanted
   //to cache locally???
}
```

Then, what is the point on page 24? How can I avoid the passing around of my collections if the DbSet.Local is only usable inside the using- block? Furthermore, how can I benefit from the change tracking if I use these short-lived context instances not handing over any cache data to each others under the hood? So, if the contexts should be short-lived for freeing resources such as connections, have I to give up the caching for this? I.e. I can’t use both at the same time (short-lived connections but long-lived cache)? So my only option would be to store the results returned by the query in my own variables, exactly what is discouraged in the motivation on page 24?

I am developing a WPF application which maybe will also become multi-tiered in the future, involving WCF. I know Julia has an example of this in her book, but I currently don’t have access to it. I found several others on the web, e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc700340.aspx (old ObjectContext, but good in explaining the inter-layer-collaborations). There, a long-lived context is used (although the disadvantages are mentioned, but no solution to these provided).
It’s not only that the single Destinations.Local gets lost, as you surely know all other entities fetched by the query are, too.

[Edit]:
After some more reading in Julia Lerman’s book, it seems to boil down to that EF does not have 2nd level caching per default; with some (considerable, I think) effort, however, ones can add 3rd party caching solutions, as is also described in the book and in various articles on MSDN, codeproject etc.

I would have appreciated if this problem had been mentioned in the section about DbSet.Local in the DbContext book that it is in fact a first level cache which is destroyed when the using {} block ends (just my proposal to make it more transparent to the readers). After first reading I had the impression DbSet.Local would always return the same reference (Singleton-style) also in the second using {} block despite the new DbContext instance.

But I am still unsure whether the 2nd level cache is the way to go for my WPF application (as Julia mentions the 2nd level cache in her article for distributed applications)? Or is the way to go to get my aggregate root instances (DDD, Eric Evans) of my domain model into memory by one or some queries in a using {} block, disposing the DbContext and only holding the references to the aggregate instances, this way avoiding a long-lived context? It would be great if you could help me with this decision.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh394143.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/435142/Entity-Framework-Second-Level-Caching-with-DbConte
http://blog.3d-logic.com/2012/03/31/using-tracing-and-caching-provider-wrappers-with-codefirst/

Answer (score 0):

The [`Local` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbset.local?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) provides a “local view of all Added, Unchanged, and Modified entities in this set”. Like all change tracking it is specific to the context you are currently using.

The DB Context is a workspace for loading data and preparing changes.

If two users were to add changes at the same time, they must not know of the others changes before they saved them. They may discard their prepared changes which suddenly would lead to problems for other other user as well.

A DB Context should be short lived indeed, but may be longer than super short when necessary. Also consider that you may not save resources by keeping it short lived if you do not load and discard data but only add changes you will save. But it is not only about resources but also about the DB state potentially changing while the DB Context is still active and has data loaded; which may be important to keep in mind for longer living contexts.

If you do not know yet all related changes you want to save into the database at once then I suggest you do not use the DB Context to store your changes in-memory but in a data structure in your code.

You can of course use entity objects for doing so without an active DB Context. This makes sense if you do not have another appropriate data class for it and do not want to create one, or decide preparing the changes in them make more sense. You can then use [`DbSet.Attach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbset.attach?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) to attach the entities to a DB Context for saving the changes when you are ready.